# Conditionally append file contents

Tags: python

I have a source file with contents which needs to be appended to destination file after checking if the all the lines in source file (as a group) are not already there in destination file.

If it's already found in destination file, I should not again append as that would duplicate the contents in the destination file.

This is essentially comparing blocks of lines as a whole.
Is there a way to do this in python without using regex?

Comment: Why you think you should use regular expressions? Load the content of files as strings and try to find the first string in the second one.

Comment: ya.you r right. Thank u for showing me a simpler way .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
src = open('source').read()
if src not in open('dest').read():
    with open('dest', 'a') as dst:
        dst.write(src)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can load the whole file in memory as a single string then you can simply use `count`:

```
import os

f = open("the_file_name", 'r+')
s1 = "the block of text\nwith newlines!\nyou will search in the file"
s2 = f.read() # s2 now has the whole file
if s2.count(s1) > 0:
    # seek to end and append s1
    f.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
    f.write(s1)
```

Comment: Hi , I tried your method . It throws an error file "IOError: File not open for writing" .Please help

Comment: Yes, I forgot the mode. Added, just for the sake of it.